# Current time in IO monad

Tags: haskell

If I have the following, for example:

```
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX

t = getPOSIXTIME
```

Then t :: IO POSIXTime. That means it is in the IO monad, this much I understand. Is there any way to get the value out of the monad to use in other functions in the program? I don't want to output the value to the terminal.

I apologise for such a newbie question, but the more monad tutorials I read the less I understand any of it. This is essentially more a question about monads than specifically about time.

Comment: Monad tutorials are a bit of a weird phenomenon; indeed I don't think any of them on their own are very helpful for understanding Haskell's way to do IO. But [_general_ Haskell introductions](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Books) most certainly are helpful; my favourite remains [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/). Do read one of those books, it's the most effective way to get into Haskell. — For now, just follow Yuan Wang's advice: "retrieval arrows" `t <- getPOSIXTIME` in `do`-blocks. You don't really need to understand what role monads play in all of this right now, you'll get it later.

Comment: When you say "get the value out of the monad to use in other functions in the program" this is the reverse of what pure functional programming recommends. Instead, you go write all those other parts of your program as pure functions, and then, at the very last second, you *use* them *inside of* the IO monad which is providing the tiny impure hook into the real world to get the system time (and input strings, and arguments, etc. etc.). Instead of thinking how can I use a monad to suck a value in, think about how to wire everything up to "just work" once it is "applied" *inside* the monad.

Answer (score 6):

If your other functions expect `POSIXTime`, you can wrap them inside `do` notation.

The easiest way is probably to put it in `main`. Assuming your other function is named `f` then:

```
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX

main :: IO ()
main = do
    t <- getPOSIXTIME
    f t
```

e.g.

```
ghc time XXX.hs
./time
```

`t` inside the `do` notation is `POSIXTime`, not `IO POSIXTime`.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_Notation